# Problem with defining a bivariate piecewise function

Tags: functions, piecewise

I want to define the following function in Mathematica in order to evaluate its partial derivative later,

$$C(u,v)= (1+\theta) uv + \theta(u+v-1) F(u+v-1)$$

$$F(a)= 1\quad \text{if} \quad a \ge 0 \quad \text{and}\quad  F(a)= 0\quad  \text{if} \quad a< 0$$

First I tried the Max function,

```
theta1 = -0.0738;
c[u_, v_] := (1 + theta1)*u*v + theta1* Max[u + v - 1, 0];
```

But it seems, the function doesn't account for $u+v-1 = 0$. To fix this I tried a piecewise function,

```
theta1 = -0.0738;
c[u_, v_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1 + theta1)*u*v + theta1* (u + v - 1), (u + v - 1) >= 0},
    {(1 + theta1)*u*v, (u + v - 1) < 0}}];
```

But the problem persists. To visualize it I plotted the function I wrote,

[image]

From the graph we can see it is not defined for some $u$ and $v$ (looks like $u + v - 1=0$). I'm wondering how to fix it.

Edit:

To be more specific, I want to plot $\frac{\partial C(u,v)}{\partial u}\vert_{u= u_0}$ for $u_0\in \{0.25, 0.5, 0.75\}$. Here is what happens for $u=0.5$,

[image]

Comment: use Plot3D[c[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None]

Comment: @RolandF My problem is not with the plot itself. I need to correctly define the function since I need to find its partial derivative.

Comment: I don't see any problem 


         Plot3D[\[Piecewise] {
   {-0.0738` + 0.9262` v, u + v >= 1},
   {0.9262` v, u + v < 1}
  }, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None]

Answer (score 1):

Not reinventing the wheel,

```
theta1 = -0.0738;
c[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := (1 + theta1)*u*v +  
theta1*(u+v-1)*UnitStep[u + v - 1];
Plot3D[c[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[D[c[u, v], u]], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

works well. The partial derivative is not continuous and defined on the line `u+v-1==0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

theta1 = -0.0738 // Rationalize;

c[u_, v_] := Piecewise[{{(1 + theta1)*u*v, u + v - 1 < 0}},
   (1 + theta1)*u*v + theta1] // Simplify

D[c[u, v], {{u, v}}]

(* {(4631 v)/5000, (4631 u)/5000} *)
```